# Изучаю qt по Шлее,возникает ошибка, с которой не могу справиться

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Книга "Qt 5.10 Профессиональное программирование на QT". В качестве среды использую QT creater 4.10.1,Qt 5.13.1.

После прочтения главы про сигналы и слоты я понял как они работают и приступил к реализации первого примера из книги. К сожалению,появляются какие то ошибки,которые я не понимаю.

Суть примера заключается в реализации класса counter. Ниже прилагаю хидер

```
#ifndef MY_SUPER_FILE_H
#define MY_SUPER_FILE_H

#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject {
       Q_OBJECT
   private:
          int m_n_value;
   public:
         Counter();
   public slots:
         void slotInc();
   signals:
         void goodbye();
         void counterChanged(int);
};


#endif // MY_SUPER_FILE_H
```

Ниже прилагаю содержание файла реализации.

```
#include "my_super_file.h"


Counter::Counter(): QObject(),m_n_value(0)
{

}


void Counter::slotInc()
{
   emit counterChanged(++m_n_value);
    if (m_n_value==5)
        emit goodbye();
}
```

А вот main

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "my_super_file.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl("0");
    QPushButton cmd("ADD");
    Counter counter;

    lbl.show();
    cmd.show();

    QObject::connect(&cmd,SIGNAL(clicked()),&counter,SLOT(slotInc()));

    QObject::connect(&counter,SIGNAL(counterChanged(int)),&lbl,SLOT(setNum(int)));

    QObject::connect(&counter,SIGNAL(goodbye()),&a,SLOT(quit()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Собственно если просто, подсоединить header к файлу реализации и скомпилировать, то ничего не ругается, но уже после определения реализации конструктора появляются такие ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ещё написать определение слота SlotInc,то получаю ещё вот такой набор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но эти все ошибки появляются,если ещё нет обращения к этому классу в функции main. Если реализация в main есть, то ошибок, само собой больше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очистите и пересоберите проект

Comment: И qmake запустите ручками

Comment: спасибо большое,помогло. Пойду читать мануалы по тому что такое qmake